# Using SASS/LESS with AngularUI

Tags: angularjs, sass, less, angular-ui

I have never used a css preprocessor.

I want to use angularjs with angularUI (bootstrap) and I would like to know wether there is any disadvantage in using SASS vs LESS. Or is there a total independency and I am totally free to use SASS or LESS with AngularJS and AngularUI bootstrap.

Maybe AngularUI has builtin support for SASS or LESS so I should favor one of those?

Comment: "Disadvantage in using LESS vs. SASS" is the warning language here.  We try to stay away from opinions on this site.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Its not a question about using LESS vs SASS there is a direct context which is angularjs + angularUI. And I would like to know the traps that could wait on me if using one of those pre processors.

Comment: @HelloWorld Same thing applies to any other A vs B comparison.  It's about as productive as a tabs vs spaces discussion.

Comment: @HelloWorld "What traps await me with X" is pretty broad, not to mention, -- which answer is the right answer? Is it the answer with the most traps? The answer that's the longest? What is objectively correct there? (going back to the 'opinion based' close reason).  If you really want this question re-opened, and you think it should be opened, your best bet is to ask on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) and get community support for re-opening it.  As it stands, this question needs a bit more direction and a bit less open-endedness.

Comment: As I understand, if you looking for solution that allows using LESS or CSS preprocessor on client side then you can look at "Angular.less" addon ( http://angularless.github.io ) because Angular has not native support for that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Angular-UI is not dependent on any preprocessor, only the rendered CSS. You can use whatever you want, SASS, LESS, or the CSS straight from Bootstrap, as long as it ends up as valid Bootstrap 3 CSS.

Now that SASS is officially supported by Bootstrap (in a separate github repo), you're free to choose whichever (SASS or LESS) you want. There have been some articles showing the strengths and weaknesses between the two (for [example](http://css-tricks.com/sass-vs-less/)), but in the end there is no clear advantage of one over the other. The main reason it's great to have options is that if you're already using one, you don't have to use the other when including Bootstrap.

For what it's worth, it seems like people are starting to prefer SASS over LESS these days.

Comment: If you looking for solution that allows to render LESS to CSS on client side (Angular) please take a look at "Angular.Less" directive ( https://angularless.github.io/angular.less/ )